# Web Push notification payload ist null when sending ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, service-worker, web-push

I am trying to send binary data from a Node.js server to a JavaScript service worker using the Web Push API.

On the Node.js side I use the [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) library and send the message with

```js
webpush.sendNotification(subscription, buffer)
```

I get a status 201 and I receive the push message on the browser side.
When I look at the Push Messaging log in the DevTools, I can even see the binary payload (encoded as UTF-8), and it says that the message was encrypted.

But when I try to get the ArrayBuffer in the service worker like this, `event.data` is `null`:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
})
```

I don't understand how the data can be `null` if it was received by the client side.